# Ensuring that document doesn't exists friestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm implementing one to one chat for an Android app in Firestore. I'm storing all the chat data in a separate collection. A document in this collection looks like this:

```
{
    participant1: "kd94992nnd9",
    participant2: "49di9niso3s",
    p1Name: "...",
    p2Name: "...",
    messages: [/*messages are stored her*/],
    //Some metadata about the chats
}
```

In my app, the user can press button and directly start chatting with some other user. When the user presses this button I create a new document in this collection that contains `userIds` of both users and all the messages.

To prevent duplication I want to ensure that **only one** document exists for any 2 users, no matter who started the chat. By using the `userIds` of the 2 participants how do I check if a document already exists with their messages? I tried using a query like this:

```
    DatabaseService.getDbInstance().collection("conversations")
        .whereEqualTo("participant1", currentUser.uid)
        .whereEqualTo("participant2", targetUser.uid)
        .get()
```

The problem with this approach is that it creates a second document where the values of `participant1` and `participant2` are switched. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Problem with this approach is that it creates a second document where the values of `participant1` and `participant2` are switched.

In that case, you should check that first. So before you create another conversation between `participant1` and `participant2` check if a conversation between `participant2` and `participant1` already exists. If it exists then add the message in that conversation, otherwise create a new one.

If you are also interested in another approach, here you can find a tutorial on how to create a complete and functional [Firestore Chat App](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb). You can check that database schema against yours. The problem of duplicity is solved.

Comment: Are you sayiing I should change the order of my `whereEqualTo`??

Comment: No, you just need to check if the opposite exists. If `.whereEqualTo("participant2", currentUser.uid).whereEqualTo("participant1", targetUser.uid)` exists, add the messages to the existing conversation, otherwise create it.

Comment: Hi, I found out that its now creating 2 documents with same values for the 2 participants. Do you have any idea on how to go about this?

Comment: Without seeing your code, I cannot be much of a help. So please elaborate a new question and add all the needed code so we can take a look at it.